# git-sync for kubernetes, Can I control the target directory?

Tags: git, kubernetes

My git-sync container for kubernetes is up and running.  When I `$ cd` into the directory they appear like this:

```
deployment-apps/
   - mygit_sync_repo.git/
      - app1/
```

My question:
Can I set git-sync to pull files so app1 is inside the same directory as mygit_sync_repo.git.  I want for deployment-apps/ to consume app1 directly.

```
deployment-apps/
   - app1/
   - mygit_sync_repo.git/
```

So far, I have tried to set

```
 - name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
  value: /
```

then I tried

```
- name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
value: "."
```

I didn't think these would actually work.  But I haven't found a lot of example use-cases to learn from.

my current manifest:

```
    - mountPath: /.../deployment-apps
      name: git-sync-volume
    - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
      value: https://redacted.git
    - name: GIT_SYNC_BRANCH
      value: master
    - name: GIT_SYNC_USERNAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: username
          name: redacted-secret
    - name: GIT_SYNC_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: redactedtoken
          name: redacted-secret
    - name: GIT_SYNC_PERMISSIONS
      value: "0777"
    - name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
      value: /git
    image: git-sync-redacted
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: git-sync
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /git
      name: git-sync-volume
```

I suppose another way to ask this question is can git pull down files without its parent directory? (I've seen some posts on this topic)  And can this happen with git-sync?

Thanks

Comment: did you got answer

Comment: since git-sync behaves like any git clone, the response below answers my original question.  For my specific project I came up with a way to work with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the path for `git-sync` to clone where you want to you need to use [GIT_SYNC_DEST](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync#parameters) env variable:

> the name of (a symlink to) a directory in which to check-out files
> under `--root` (defaults to the leaf dir of `--repo`)

Remember that `GIT_SYNC_DEST` needs to be a subdirectory under the `GIT_SYNC_ROOT` directory.

For example:

```
- name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
  value: /home
- name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
  value: "app1"
```

will clone to `/home/app1`.

Comment: what in case if we have multiple subfolders(app1,app2)